# Tesseract fails to scan when text is aligned center

Tags: python, tesseract

It works fine if the text is aligned to th left like this

Bộ phim “Chúa tế Godzilla: Đế vương bất tứ" do ai đạo diễn?

Dan Harris

Simon Kinberg

Michael Dougherty

but when the question is aligned to center like this:

Bộ phim “Chúa tế Godzilla: Đế vương bất tứ"

do ai đạo diễn?

Dan Harris

Simon Kinberg

Michael Dougherty

---

In this case, sometimes tesseract gives me some nonsense words, sometimes it cannot scan anything at all. And here is the code I use:

```
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.resize(gray, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

if args["preprocess"] == "thresh":
           gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
                        cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

elif args["preprocess"] == "blur":
                gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)
filename = "Screens/{}.png".format(os.getpid())            

cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), lang='vie')
```

Please tell me how can I solve this problem? I want Tesseract to work fine with any situation.

Comment: provide input image

Comment: Have you tried with a different PSM?